# How to retrieve the closest specific ID when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the `mesg_id` when the user clicks on a button it shows a popup and inside it , it will show the `mesg_id`

but the issue that i am having not that i cant retrieve the `mesg_id` is that it takes the one on top not the one the user clicks on example :

[image]

```
<div class="msg-action">
    <p id="mesg_id"><?php echo $msg_id; ?></p>
    <a class="msg-icon popup-button"  href="" data-target="#reply-popup"><img src="images/reply.png"></img></a>
    <a class="msg-icon" href="<?php echo "index?message=" . $row['id'] . ""; ?>" ><img src="images/linedfav.png" id='img'></img></a>
</div>
```

This is the script that shows the pop up when the reply is clicked and it takes the `mesg_id`

```
/* modle-popup*/

jQuery(document).ready(function(){


    jQuery(".popup-button").click(function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery("body").addClass("sitemodal-open");
      jQuery(".sitemodal").addClass("in");
      var textareaValue = $('#mesg_id').html();
      document.getElementById("showMesgID").innerHTML = textareaValue;
    });

    jQuery('.sitemodal .sitemodal-dialog').click(function($){
       $.stopPropagation();
    });

    jQuery(".close-popup ,.sitemodal").click(function(){
      jQuery("body").removeClass("sitemodal-open");
      jQuery(".sitemodal").removeClass("in");
      document.getElementById("showMesgID").innerHTML = "";
    });
});
```

how can i get the `mesg_id` the one the user clicks on not the one on top

Comment: id's have to be unique

Comment: [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use an ID in an element once per page.

```
<div id="myid">testing</div>
<div id="myid">testing 2</div>
```

The first element takes precedent because it was the first element with that ID.  You need to assign each element their own unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ID for multiple elements. ID is meant to be unique for every element. You need to use CLASS instead. and then use closest() and find() to get the value from the element in the same modal.

Html:

```
<div class="msg-action">
    <p class="mesg_id"><?php echo $msg_id; ?></p>
    <a class="msg-icon popup-button"  href="" data-target="#reply-popup"><img src="images/reply.png"></img></a>
    <a class="msg-icon" href="<?php echo "index?message=" . $row['id'] . ""; ?>" ><img src="images/linedfav.png" id='img'></img></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(".popup-button").click(function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery("body").addClass("sitemodal-open");
      jQuery(".sitemodal").addClass("in");
      var textareaValue = $(this).closest('.msg-action').find('.mesg_id').html();
      document.getElementById("showMesgID").innerHTML = textareaValue;
    });
```